# Correct syntax for using php to set <div> attribute

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I need to set a div's background colour using PHP. Here's what I'm doing at the moment:

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:"<?php echo $permacolour; ?>"">
```

However, this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:<?=$permacolour?>">
```

quotes do not belong to PHP syntax. PHP tags are `<?`, `<?php` and `?>` only

Comment: Good answer, but I'd note that `<?php ?>` is a perfectly acceptable syntax for this, OP doesn't have to use `<?= ?>` - it's the quotes, not the PHP tags, that are the problem.

Comment: Also, the `<?=` in this example is a short hand way of writing `<?php echo`

Comment: And requires short tags be enabled in PHP's ini file! :)

Comment: @Ascherer  Nice.  Good to know.  Fingers crossed I'll start seeing less Smarty use as a result.

Answer (score 4):

```
style="background-color:"<?php echo $permacolour; ?>""
```

You have two sets of quotes here. Try this:

```
style="background-color:<?php echo $permacolour; ?>"
```

Answer (score 4):

To be near your original post, here's the correct way :

```
<div class="box" style="background-color: <?php echo $permacolour; ?>">
```

The problem is that you were writing the background color surrounded by double quotes. The result would have been like

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:"red"">
```

instead of

```
<div class="box" style="background-color: red">
```

So just remove the double quotes between the value you are good to go.

Of course, this suppose you defined `$permacolour` or you made sure the value of `$permacolour` is sanitized and filtered if inputed by a user.

The answer of @your-common-sense is based on the shorthand syntax that is not always activated on hosted servers.

Comment: Worth noting, Moving forward in php, after 5.4, `<?=` will always be available, regardless of the `short_tag` setting

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:<?php echo $permacolour; ?>;">
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the double quotes

```
style="<?php echo $permacolour ; ?>"
```

or without quotes at all would be easier for some versions in html

```
style=<?php echo $permacolor ;?>
```